What would be the best solution to allow access to files in laravel storage from a client application on another domain?
What would be the best solution to allow access to files in laravel storage from a client application on another domain?
The following helped me:
location /storage/ {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

I’m not sure that this is the best solution and I don’t really like it, but I couldn’t find another way to solve the issue of accessing storage files through a request (axios, fetch) from a third-party client application :(
My cors.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |------------------------------------------------ -------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |------------------------------------------------ -------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'storage/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];

My Http/Kernel.php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize;
use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors;
use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken;
use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth;
use App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use App\Http\Middleware\IikoWebhookNameFilter;
use App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance;
use App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated;
use App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings;
use App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies;
use App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        TrustProxies::class,
        HandleCors::class,
        PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        ValidatePostSize::class,
        TrimStrings::class,
        ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            StartSession::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
            CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            // \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => Authenticate::class,
        'auth.check' => CheckAuth::class,
        'auth.basic' => AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => Authorize::class,
        'guest' => RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'webhook.iiko.name.filter' => IikoWebhookNameFilter::class,
    ];
}

I tried sending fetch requests
await fetch("https://example.com/storage/2/1002683_1707758192_57.png");

and got a cors error until I updated my nginx config.
I would really like to hear the community’s opinion, thanks in advance to all participants

I think the best solution is to create an API for saving the file in storage. Use Laravel's storage system in the API to save the file.
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileName = time() . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;

$path = "image" . $fileName;
Storage::disk('local')->put($path, file_get_contents($file));

In the filesystem.php config verify the code is correct
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'throw' => false,
],

Then You can generate the URL.
$url = Storage::disk('public')->url($fileUrl);

the $fileUrl here is the path you are given while saving the file
